# Using a nodejs server and Pug how can I display elements from a list one at a time and iterate using a button?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, pug

I am very new to Web development and NodeJs servers and Pug this is my first time using any of this. Essentially I want to have a box which would be a div and I want to dynamically change the data in that box based on a list from a JSON file for now, eventually when I get this working I will be using a database to supply that list. I have setup my server and have setup the basic part of my Pug code using some tutorials online. I know I have to use some javascript to get this done but I can't even access my list within the "script" part of my pug code which confuses me even more. Here is the code I have so far:

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const testTweets = require('./testTweets.json');
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', {
    title: 'Tweet Labeler',
    data: testTweets.tweets
  });
});

const server = app.listen(9000,() => {
   console.log(`Express running → PORT ${server.address().port}`);
});
```

index.pug:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title #{title}
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/style.css')
    meta(name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1")
  body
    main
      block header
        header.header
          h1 #{title}
      block content
      div.container
          h2#label Tweet ID:
          div.tweetBox
          button.button-next Next
          script.
            var maxLength = data.length
            console.log("In the script tag!" + maxLength)
```

Note* the script part doesn't work at all it gives me an error saying "data" is not defined

testTweets.json:

```
{
  "tweets": [
    {
      "id":"0",
      "text": "this is tweet index 0",
      "relevancy": "unknown"
    },
    {
      "id":"1",
      "text": "this is tweet index 1",
      "relevancy": "unknown"
    },
    {
      "id":"2",
      "text": "this is tweet index 2",
      "relevancy": "unknown"
    },
    {
      "id":"3",
      "text": "this is tweet index 3",
      "relevancy": "unknown"
    },
    {
      "id":"4",
      "text": "this is tweet index 4",
      "relevancy": "unknown"
    }
  ]
}
```

Very basic json file to just see if I can get this to work.

And heres what the page looks like:
Ideally the white box would get filled with like the text from each element in the list and then when they click next it would display the text of the next element. 
[image]

I have looked through stackoverflow and other forums but I just can't seem to find something similar to this using PUG and i've looked at approaches from other languages but I am really struggling since I can't even access the list that I am passing in called data because my console just errors out and says "data not defined" but if I use it regularly(not in the script) part in Pug it definitely is defined. Thanks in advance to anyone who takes the time to help with this really appreciate it!

Comment: The data variable is only available on the server. Easiest way i can think of would be to render h2 and div.tweetbox for every tweet on the server and add a class e.g. `hidden` which would hide all the elements except the first h2 and div. Then using the button you can add/remove the `hidden` class to show/hide the elements. Another way could be to render h2 and div empty on the server and once the page loads on the client use ajax to get data from server and then replace the text of the h2 and div with the text from tweets object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data` variable in the script tag is a client-side javascript variable and as such would not be defined as it is independent of the server-side `data` variable. You can place the server-side value of `data` in the pug javascript block by using pug's [interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html) feature.

```
div.container
  h2#label Tweet ID:
  div.tweetBox
    each tweet in data
      p=tweet.text
  button.button-next Next
  script.
    var data = !{JSON.stringify(data)};
    var maxLength = data.length;
    console.log("In the script tag!" + maxLength);
```

The `data` will be replaced during render on the server with the value JSON in the server-side data variable. You can show the tweets using pug's `each` iterator to iterate over data or you can use client-side javascript to do it.

Comment: Thanks didn't know about this! I will be trying to fiddle around with the javascript to get this to work! I think if I do it using the client-side javascript it will be easier to translate when I do it with my database data since I will eventually need to post some data back to a database which I think is easier in javascript? But not exactly sure how I will go about that right now. Also do you know if I can use jQuery with pug or should I just stick with vanilla javascript?

Comment: Also within a javascript function how would you for example change the text in lets say a header tag with the iD name lets say "label". I've been trying using like the getElementbyID method but it isn't working

Comment: You could use jQuery, vanilla JS would be better. If you have many DOM manipulations or your app grows bigger, I would recommend `react` or `vue.js`. Changing the text with getElementById can be dome with  `document.getElementById("label").innerHTML="something"`

Comment: Awesome thank you so much that worked! How did you know to use "innterHTML" rather than .text or .value which is what I saw when I was browsing around for answers. And also later when I get to sending stuff back to a database would that be done in the clientside javascript or somehow through the server with some sort of post request? Do you know of any simple guides or anything about this that might help. Thank you again for all the help!

Comment: That could have been `jQuery` you were looking at with the .text and .value . You'd need a POST request, along with some client-side ajax calls. I'm afraid I don't know of any guide in particular but Google is your friend here. If you're stuck at something you can post a question....